# C# - Byte arrays and file extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, filecontentresult

I have a byte array that I've downloaded which lacks a file extension.  I need to give this file an extension, which in my case will always be .gif, and convert back to a byte array.

I'm accomplishing the first step thus:

```
FileContentResult file = File(imageList.Single(), "image/gif");
```

I'm not sure what to do next.  FileContentResult has a FileContents parameter which is of type byte array.  I've tried using that, but it doesn't appear to contain the extension in the data.

Do byte arrays even contain the extension type?  This is my first time working with one, so my understanding of what they are and what I can do with them is lacking.

Comment: No they don't. There are ways to _try and figure it out_ based on the file header in the byte array.. but that is an incredible amount of work for something you were assuming was quick and easy. There is a GIF spec here that might help you determine how to detect a GIF based on the header: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt

Comment: @Simon So the file extension for any file would not be included in a byte array?

Comment: Not at all. The byte array is literally the bytes that make up the file. If the extension is part of the file content.. then it will be there. But it won't be in the same place in every file.. and to find it would require knowing how to parse the format of every file you wanted to support.

Comment: I don't get it. You have this byte array that you want to send as part of the response back to the browser, so I'm assuming that you already have some "name" for the image. Why not just append ".gif" to it and set the FileCOntentResult.FileDownloadName accordingly ?

Comment: Does whatever is receiving this byte array also know it will always be a .gif? If so, it can just treat it as such, can it not? Otherwise, I think passing the byte array along with some meta data containing the file type might be the easiest way around this. Edit -- what @mrlucmorin said 6 seconds before me :)

Comment: @mrlucmorin I'm passing the byte array to a service that I honestly know nothing about.  The end result is to attach an image to an e-mail.  Perhaps the service can detect the file type in a manner that Simon Whitehead suggested.  Given the option, it would be easier to pass the FileContentResult.  Thanks for the help, all.

Answer (score 0):

**image/gif** is a mime type used on the internet to tell the client how to interpret a set of data.

It is not required if you save the data to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your wording of the problem domain is a little misleading.  When you use the term "downloaded", do you mean "retrieved by way of an http connection", or "read (past tense) from a disk file, or a database field"??

I'm thinking it's the latter case -- so I'll proceed.

Raw data, when pulled in this way, will NOT have a filename.  Why??? A filename is a pointer to some data within a file system.  If you have a brown paper bags marked "green things", and you happen to pull an apple out of the bag, there's intrinsically within that apple to associate that apple (raw data) with the bag marked "green things" (the pointer).

Since your code makes reference to a FileContentResult, I infer that you are using MVC, and that you are within controller code, trying to deliver the byte array back to a browser.

If you take a peek at the link below here, you might find that the FileContentResult object has a neat property called "FileDownloadName".  This is where you want to set the name of the file - append the extension.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult(v=vs.118).aspx